# Identity Server4 and OAuth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, .net-core-2.2

I am building my own API in .Net Core 2.2 for fun and to learn more. I am at the point  I want to secure it with JWT tokens. I have built my own authentication and validation with JWT to understand what's going on. But I thought I would use some of the already established frameworks for this instead of inventing the wheel again. I was thinking of Identity server 4 and OAuth2. So my question is, does anybody have any good resources, guides or tutorials that cover both the Identity server and OAuth2 and how the work together.

I have found this [article](https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4) and I searched PluralSight and found some but nothing that covers both technologies. I thought I would ask the community here before I dive in.

Answer (score 3):

OAuth2 and Identity Servery 4 do not work together.

What OAuth2 is, is a specification. I was at a point you are and you have to get it through your head that OAuth2 is an idea/blueprint/schematic/plan/specification/framework which just describes how to make authentication with JWT possible. If you want to understand the idea of OAuth2 you got to read the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) there is no easy way about just read it.

Part of IdentityServer4 takes the OAuth2 spec and abstracts it into an easy to use API that integrates with the dotnet core framework. Saying 'part' because IdentityServer4 provides so much more than just an implementation of OAuth2. To learn IdentityServer4 [read the docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Furthermore you can read the [oidc spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html). This is the spec for authenticating the client with JWT.

I'd also recommend watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5p72gTdx_M), where Brock Allen gives a tour of IdentityServer4.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide on how to stand up a simple OAuth2 server using IdentityServer.
https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/simplestOAuth.html

They also released all the source for the example here:
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Simplest%20OAuth2%20Walkthrough

The IdentityServer online documentation is extensive and is also a good reference and resource as you move through setup.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html

Good luck!